# Do the names of the args passed to main() matter

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

I know that to use command line arguments in C you do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
//use argc and argv
}
```

Today I was thinking about it and I realized I have never not seen them called `argc` and `argv`. Is it a requirement that they are called this or is it just convention? If it is required why is this the case?

Could I do something like this:

```
int main(int length, char**myinput){
//use length as you would argc and myinput
// as you would argv
}
```

I haven't had a chance to write a program to test it out yet.

Comment: `argc` and `args` is just a convention that came down from the time where characters were precious...

Comment: You should *totally* call them like: `int main(int NumberOfProgramArguments, char **NullTerminatedArrayOfPointersToProgramArguments )`

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky that's seldom true for C. Lots of things can appear to work when in fact they don't.

Comment: I think you could even call one of them `main`

Comment: @2501 However, any decent C programmer will recognize the meaning of `int main(int argc, char** args)`...

Comment: @2501 I don't have any problem using `argv` and `argc` I was just curious

Comment: @Quentin What do you mean? If you test it out and it works, there's a chance that it's imaginary not really works? I don't get it I think.

Comment: int main(int i, char **j) works too

Comment: This may explain the etymology of argc and argv: [Where did the convention of naming command line arguments as 'argv' come from?](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196654/where-did-the-convention-of-naming-command-line-arguments-as-argv-come-from)

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky I insist on "*appear* to work". Undefined behaviour is one such source of things that seem to work until they don't work anymore for no apparent reason.

Comment: @Quentin If it's undefined behaviour, then it's different, but if none said it. You actually found an interesting question, why in this specific situation, that behaviour is occurring.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky no one mentionned it indeed, but it's just a fair warning that in C you can't just "try it and see if it works", because invisible bugs do exist :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C standard says that you can call them whatever you want.

> 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup
>
> 1 The function called at program startup is named main. The implementation declares no prototype for this
>   function. It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, **though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared**): *[..]*

In [What does int argc, char *argv[] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean), answerer [meager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024202/3920237) says that `argc` and `argv` are named so by convention (argument count and argument vector respectively).

Answer (score 2):

It is just a convention, there is no requirement on the names.  They are user-defined parameters like any other, so use whatever names you want.